# How to handle with "java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.widget.TextView"?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm new in android dev. So I decided to start making todo app. I wanted to make a window where a user may enter title and description of his tasks. After using fragment+recycler view I started to get this error:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.bignerdranch.android.taskmaster, PID: 8887
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bignerdranch.android.taskmaster/com.bignerdranch.android.taskmaster.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.widget.TextView

But I cannot understand what is wrong. I've checked my MainActivity, Fragment and Adapter for recycler view. This error makes my app stop all the time.  I would appreciate your help!

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.taskmaster


import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider


import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.bignerdranch.android.taskmaster.databinding.ActivityMainBinding



class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var todoAdapter:TodoAdapter
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var taskViewModel: TaskViewModel
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        setContentView(binding.root)
        val tvTodoTitle = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvTodoTitle)
        taskViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(TaskViewModel::class.java)


        todoAdapter = TodoAdapter(mutableListOf())
        binding.rvTodoItems.adapter = todoAdapter
        binding.rvTodoItems.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        binding.btnAddTodo.setOnClickListener{
            NewTaskSheet().show(supportFragmentManager,"NewTaskTag")
            }
        taskViewModel.title.observe(this){
            tvTodoTitle.text=String.format("Task:%s",it)
        }

    }

}
```

NewTaskSheet

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.taskmaster

import android.os.Bundle

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import com.bignerdranch.android.taskmaster.databinding.FragmentNewTaskSheetBinding
import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialogFragment




class NewTaskSheet : BottomSheetDialogFragment(){

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentNewTaskSheetBinding
    private lateinit var taskViewModel: TaskViewModel


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentNewTaskSheetBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view:View,savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val activity = requireActivity()
        taskViewModel= ViewModelProvider(activity).get(TaskViewModel::class.java)
        binding.btnSave.setOnClickListener{
            saveAction()
        }

    }



    private fun saveAction(){
        taskViewModel.title.value=binding.title.text.toString()
        taskViewModel.description.value=binding.description.text.toString()
        binding.title.setText("")
        binding.description.setText("")
        dismiss()
    }


}
```

TodoAdapter

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.taskmaster


import android.graphics.Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.CheckBox
import android.widget.TextView


import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bignerdranch.android.taskmaster.databinding.ItemTodoBinding



class TodoAdapter(
    private val todos: MutableList<Todo>
):RecyclerView.Adapter<TodoAdapter.TodoViewHolder>() {

    class TodoViewHolder( ItemTodoBinding: ItemTodoBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(ItemTodoBinding.root)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TodoViewHolder {

        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val ItemTodoBinding = ItemTodoBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
        return TodoViewHolder(

            return TodoViewHolder(ItemTodoBinding)
        )


    }





    private fun toggleStrikeThrough(tvTodoTitle: TextView, isChecked:Boolean){
        if(isChecked){
            tvTodoTitle.paintFlags = tvTodoTitle.paintFlags or STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
        }else{
            tvTodoTitle.paintFlags = tvTodoTitle.paintFlags and STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG.inv()
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TodoViewHolder, position: Int) {
          val curTodo = todos[position]

          holder.itemView.apply{
              val tvTodoTitle = findViewById(R.id.tvTodoTitle) as TextView
              tvTodoTitle.text = curTodo.title

              val cbDone = findViewById(R.id.cbDone) as CheckBox
              cbDone.isChecked = curTodo.isChecked
              toggleStrikeThrough(tvTodoTitle, curTodo.isChecked)
              cbDone.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
                  toggleStrikeThrough(tvTodoTitle, isChecked)
                  curTodo.isChecked = !curTodo.isChecked


              }

              cbDone.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener{

                      todos.removeAll{todo->
                          todo.isChecked
                      }

                      notifyDataSetChanged()



              })

        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
          return todos.size
    }

}
```

activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvTodoItems"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnAddTodo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddTodo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:text="Add"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnTodoDone"
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTodoDone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Done"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

item_todo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:paddingStart="8dp"
    android:paddingEnd="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTodoTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Example"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/cbDone"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbDone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

P.S The description of this error tells me that it is all in 25 line in MainActivity but I don't know what is the problem there. Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe `tvTodoTitle` does not exist in your activity_main.xml. Anyway, you are using view binding, so there is no need to use `findViewById`, simply `binding.tvTodoTitle` will give you the `TextView`. If `tvTodoTitle` does not exist in `binding`, that means you haven't define `tvTodoTitle` in your xml.

Comment: I have added two xml files here. tvTodoTitle is in item_todo. But I want to use it for MainActivity. So I tried this because I don't know any other options

Comment: You should not (and no need) to access `tvTodoTitle` in `MainActivity`. `tvTodoTitle` should only be accessed from within `onBindViewHolder` of `TodoAdapter`

Comment: So... how can i change my code? Just I use tvTodoTitle in MainActivity with view model, and I cannot use this model in TodoAdapter

Comment: What is the purpose of `taskViewModel.title.observe(this){ tvTodoTitle.text=String.format("Task:%s",it)}` ? I don't know your intention but any access to `tvTodoTitle` outside `TodoAdapter` should simply be removed. If you are trying to access it outside that mean you are intending to do something wrong and there should be a proper way to achieve your intention.

Comment: Well, if user click button add, the window of task details pops up. Then this user enter title and description. After that the title of this task is on the screen. So I have tried to do this. But something went wrong as you can see...

Comment: Can you post your view model? Are you following some kind of tutorial? It looks like you have trouble understanding how recycler view and view model work.

Comment: I have watched two different tutorials. And I have tried to do something on my own.

Comment: In my view model there are only two fields: title and description.

Comment: `ViewModel` is a representation of your UI state. If your UI contains a list of tasks, your activity view model should contain a `LiveData<List<TodoTask>>`, where `TodoTask` is a data class representing individual task (i.e. contains `title` and `description`). When you add task, you create a new `TodoTask` and update the `LiveData`, while the main UI observe the `LiveData`, and notify changes to the `RecyclerView` with the updated `List`

Comment: Oh I started to understand. Thank you. I will try to rewrite my code;)

Comment: Can you plz send me a link to documentation on this issue?

Comment: Here is a [tutorial](https://medium.com/@abeythilakeudara3/todo-list-app-with-room-database-kotlin-mvvm-architecture-c5ec5d29366c) which I found very close to your case, but it also integrate android room database, you can ignore the database part and replace it with local variable.

Comment: well, but can i use dat class instead of view model here? it seems to be a little bit easier for understanding

Comment: I have tried to use data class instead of view model. There is no error. However, I cannot figure out how to get entered title from the input that is in bottom sheet dialog and give it to adapter that will print it on the screen. So...

Answer (score 1):

As you're using the View Binding feature there's no need to use this line to access your TextView

```
val tvTodoTitle = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvTodoTitle)
```

When you want to set your Title you can just do

```
binding.tvTodoTitle.text = "....."
```

That's assuming that a TextView with the name `tvTodoTitle` exists in `activity_main`

Comment: I use find view by id because tvTodoTitle is in xml file created for TodoAdapter.kt. It is not in activity_main. I want to get this id in my MainActivity. So I used find view by id and did not get any errors.

Comment: I have just added these xml files' code here